# IQ test sample patterns. Can anyone find the missing number?

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

[image]

I am fully hopeful that you can crack this puzzle.

> You need to answer with an explanation.

Comment: @Asterisk please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> $30$

because:

> In the first row, add $2$ to the $1$ and multiply with the $3$ to get $9$. In the second row, double the $4$ and multiply with the $3$ to get $24$. In the third row, we do both - add $2$ to the $5$ and double the $2$, then multiply to get $28$. If you now observe the pattern of bold/normal font for the first two columns, it repeats on the fourth row, so we add $2$ to the $4$ and multiply with the $5$ to get $30$.

Comment: bold numbers doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

**My solution is...**
$l = left$
$r = right$

> $2l + r = 15$
> $-l + r = 4 | +l$
> $r = 4 + l$
>
> $6l = 15 |:6$
> $l = 2.5$
> $r = 6.5$

**So the next number is:**

> $2l + 28 = 33$

(I thought that the bold numbers doesn't matter)

Comment: I don't think the process to get the answer can be complex like this

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Idea similar JonMarkPerry, but slightly different, my guess:

> **60**

RULES:

> 1)BOLD NUMBER = BOLD NUMBER +2
>
> 2) right number is multiple of first two in a row multiply by number of simple divisors of each number(beginning one, not+2) different from it (EX for 3 is 1, 4 is 2 and 1, for 6 is 3 and 2 and 1 and so on)
>
> 3)right number is not bold only if first two are not bold
>
> 4) using those rules we get (1+2)*3*1*1=9(bold) 3*4*1*2=24(not bold) (2+2)*(5+2)*1*1=28(bold)
>   so (4+2)*5*2*1=60(bold)

Comment: The number is bold or not, doesn't make sense

Comment: @RajendraSingh What exactly doesnt make sence? I totally agree that number is bold or not

Comment: as @Matti said- I thought that the bold numbers don't matter. I agree